# Created a new branch and changed from old branch -> new branch and suddenly some files are greyed out in visual studio 2022

Tags: git, visual-studio

I made some changes and created a new branch, however, some files were greyed out and it's not working properly anymore, saying there are circular dependencies even though there's nothing in their csproj that could be circular dependency and well, it was working just before I changed to this new branch I just created.

What could it be?

[image: file greyed out]

The error I'm getting now is NU1108, which is about circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by removing the project and adding it again, but that was weird. All I did was create a new branch, checkout to this new branch and bring the changes to it. Some files from project A went to project B, or from project C to project D.